# PDFBox how to remove Formatting in the Field Level

Tags: apache, pdf, pdfbox

I am using  Apache PDFBox for PDF manipulations and I need help on How to remove Formatting on the PDF Input field using Apache PDFBox. For example I have an Input field that has Data formatting and if I set value through PDFBox it is making the field blank ,, but if I remove the Format manualy(using editor) and then use SetValue it is good , So I need to strip out all the Input level formatting. See the image below I am showing the field Properties below .. I need to clear all PDF Field level Formatting as seen below..

[image: Click here to see the field Poperties]

Comment: Please edit your question to add the version, the code, link to the PDF and explain what you mean with "formatting", "data formatting", "remove formatting manualy(using editor)", and "Ma"..

Comment: those formatting settings usually are implemented by means of JavaScript. Removing all JavaScript event listeners of the fields in question, therefore, would remove formatting and would be easy to implement but that might also remove more  behaviour than necessary.